# Dspace CRIS new entiry page

Tags: dspace

I created a new entity 'courses' using cris modules in dspace cris 'jspui', but I want to know how can I add new menu entry like "project, reseachers ..." and how to create new page to browse and list the courses?

I read the documentation and I add 'courses' to cris.cfg file:

```
navbar.cris-entities = publications,researcherprofiles,orgunits,fundings,courses
```

then I add this part to cris-processor:

```
<entry key="courses">
                    <list>
                        <bean class="org.dspace.app.webui.cris.components.BrowseProcessor">
                            <property name="browseNames">
                                <list>
                                    <value>coursesname</value>
                                </list>
                            </property>
                        </bean>
                    </list>
                </entry>
```

[this is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ft1gN.png)

Can anyone give me a step by step example to add custom entity link to a browse page in cris??

Answer (score 0):

you can find some documentation about that on the official DSpace-CRIS documentation.
To create a new section like projects and researchers see:
https://wiki.duraspace.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=78163308#Custompresentation&dynamiccomponents-Definingthesitesections(Explore)

to define browse and search in such sections, see
https://wiki.duraspace.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=78153687

Hope this help

Comment: You are on the right path. You need to add the `jsp.layout.navbar-default.cris.courses` to the Messages.properties in the dspace-api to solve the ??? issue. The `coursesname` in the `BrowseProcessor` bean needs to match the definition of a browse in the dspace.cfg, i.e. you need a `webui.browse.index.<n> = coursesname:<display-type>:<sort-name>[:DESC]` see [link]https://wiki.duraspace.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=78153687#Browse&Search-Full,singlelevelbrowse[link]

Comment: I add `webui.browse.index.11 = coursesname:courses:coursesname` to dspace.cfg and `webui.itemlist.sort-option.8 = criscourses:criscourses.coursesname:title` but know the app not work. Please give me a real example. My entity `courses` and my field is `coursesname`